# Проблема со скриптом. jQuery, событие .click()

Tags: javascript, jquery

При повторном нажатии меню должно обратно закрываться.

```js
$('.show_hide-menu').click(function() {
  if ($('.menu').css({
      'left': '-300px'
    })) {
    $('.menu').css({
      'left': '0',
      'transition': '0.5s'
    })
  } else {
    $('.menu').css({
      'left': '-300px',
      'transition': '0.5s'
    })
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #a7dcdd;
}

.menu {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #6ab1b3;
  position: absolute;
  left: -300px;
}

.menu ul {
  padding: 0 0 0 50px;
}

.menu ul li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 31px 0px;
  margin-top: 23px;
  margin-bottom: 23px;
}

.menu ul li a {
  color: #faf9f9;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0px 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.menu ul li:hover a {
  color: white;
  color: #c4ecec;
}

.show_hide-menu {
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: -7px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background-color: #faf9f9;
  text-align: center;
  height: 40px;
}

.menu ul li a i.fa {
  left: 0px;
  top: 31px;
}

h3 {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #6ab1b3;
}

h3:hover {
  color: #81c5c6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <script defer src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script defer src="js/script.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="show_hide-menu">
    <h3>Меню</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="menu">
    <ul class="fa fa-ul">
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-li fa-home fa-fw"></i>Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-li fa-cog fa-fw"></i>Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-li fa-image fa-fw"></i>Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-li fa-group fa-fw"></i>About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-li fa-envelope fa-fw"></i>Contacts</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `if` вы получаете объект, который не пустой, и соответственно всегда будет приведен к `true`. Самый простой вариант - просто сделайте булеву переменную, которая хранит состояние "открытости"

```js
let isVisible = false;

$('.show_hide-menu').click(function() {
  if (!isVisible) {
    $('.menu').css({
      'left': '0',
      'transition': '0.5s'
    });
  } else {
    $('.menu').css({
      'left': '-300px',
      'transition': '0.5s'
    })
  }
  
  isVisible = !isVisible;
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #a7dcdd;
}

.menu {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #6ab1b3;
  position: absolute;
  left: -300px;
}

.menu ul {
  padding: 0 0 0 50px;
}

.menu ul li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 31px 0px;
  margin-top: 23px;
  margin-bottom: 23px;
}

.menu ul li a {
  color: #faf9f9;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0px 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.menu ul li:hover a {
  color: white;
  color: #c4ecec;
}

.show_hide-menu {
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: -7px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background-color: #faf9f9;
  text-align: center;
  height: 40px;
}

.menu ul li a i.fa {
  left: 0px;
  top: 31px;
}

h3 {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #6ab1b3;
}

h3:hover {
  color: #81c5c6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <script defer src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script defer src="js/script.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="show_hide-menu">
    <h3>Меню</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="menu">
    <ul class="fa fa-ul">
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-li fa-home fa-fw"></i>Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-li fa-cog fa-fw"></i>Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-li fa-image fa-fw"></i>Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-li fa-group fa-fw"></i>About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-li fa-envelope fa-fw"></i>Contacts</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: В каких случаях в условие if (!isVisible) {} вернется true?

Comment: если `isVisible = false`, то `!isVisible = true`